# PHP curl giving 404 error on live but working fine on local

Tags: php, curl

Hi I am using php curl request. it is working fine on local but giving 404 page error with http_code 404 not found on live site. Here is code i am using:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "strJSON=" . json_encode($api_array));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Exactly same code giving perfect output on local but giving 404 page. Couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: What's the URL you are trying to access? Can you open it in your browser?

Comment: Can you ping the URL from your live server. If the server is behind a firewall it's possible there's no DNS lookup!

Comment: @DonovanSolms, yes url is fine.

Comment: @BenHillier, how to detect the exact issue via curl ?? any addition commands?

Comment: @MahaDev Use `curl_error()` to get the last error. It's the best you can get.

Comment: @BenHillier a DNS or network failure will not result in a 404. A 404 means the server can be reached, but the requested document does not exist.

Comment: First of all, determine if it's the issue at all. Do you have command line access on the server. Log in and try to ping the URL. You can also try curl from the command line.

Comment: The issue is not with cURL, but with the document you try to request in `$url`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Good point well made!

Comment: @BartFriederichs how to detect the document error? because `curl_error()` is not working

Comment: Try adding? `if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}`

Comment: @MahaDev what is the "local" URL, and what is the "live" URL? That is where you should be looking: on the server. Check server logs.